# Issue with object oriented programming and onmousedown function

Tags: javascript, html5-canvas, onmousedown

I am making a drawing application with the html5 canvas.  I am trying to use OOP and avoid all global variables.  I have a PainLab class and a drawing class

```
var PaintLab = function() {
   this.drawing = new Drawing();
   //Define some methods
   var self = this;
   canvas.addEventListener('click', MouseDown, self, false);
};

var Drawing = function() {
   this.position = { x: 4, y: 200 };
   this.size = { width: 500, height: 500 };
};
```

As you can see I have a event listener for the user clicking the canvas here is what the MouseDown function.

```
var MouseDown = function(paintLab, evt) {
  var mouseX = evt.clientX;
  var mouseY = evt.clientY;
  //Check is user clicked the drawing which is a square element on the canvas
  if (x >= paintLab.drawing.position.x && x <= paintLab.position.x + paintLab.drawing.size.width &&
    y >= paintLab.drawing.position.y && y <= paintLab.position.y + paintLab.drawing.size.height) {
    //Draw to canvas    
  }
};
```

If I use this code, clientX / Y and paintLab are undefiened.  Most likely PaintLab()'s scope deletes this information but what is the best way to overcome this?  I appreciate any help!

Answer (score 2):

Only the event object is passed to the `MouseDown` function. I'm not sure what you're thinking will happen by passing `self` as the third argument to `addEventListener` -- it's supposed to be an `options` object, and the fourth argument is for Gecko/Mozilla only: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener

> target.addEventListener(type, listener[, useCapture, wantsUntrusted  ]); // Gecko/Mozilla only

In any case, what you can do is use [bind()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind) to set the context under which your function will run:

```
canvas.addEventListener('click', MouseDown.bind(self));
```

Then, in `MouseDown`, the `this` of the function will refer to the current instance of `PaintLab`.

---

However, I would suggest you rethink your structure. Make `PaintLab` an object, and MouseDown a method of that object:

```
var PaintLab = (function() {
    var self = this;
    canvas.addEventListener('click', self.MouseDown);
    return {
        MouseDown: function(evt) {
            var mouseX = evt.clientX;
            var mouseY = evt.clientY;
            //Check is user clicked the drawing
            if (mouseX >= self.drawing.position.x && mouseX <= self.position.x + self.drawing.size.width &&
                mouseY >= self.drawing.position.y && mouseY <= self.position.y + self.drawing.size.height) {
                //Draw to canvas    
            }
        }
    }
})();
```

That way you can just reference `self` instead of messing around with `bind()`...

Note that you may need to declare `canvas` somewhere in there, but I'll leave that as an exercise for you :).

Comment: This gets rid of the issue with clientX and Y but now drawing.position.x is undefined.  What can I do to fix this.  Also note that I used prototype to declare the mouseDown function.

Comment: I'm not sure where the `drawing` property is supposed to come from. It wouldn't have worked in your original code either... How did you get that code in the first place?

Comment: I put the drawing class up in the original question hope it helps!  Also thank you for all the help so far.

Comment: Yeah, can you perhaps put together what I've shown with what you have and figure out how to combine them yourself? I'll give you a hint: `return { MouseDown: function (evt) { ... }, drawing: { position: { x: 4; `...